# What are "real-world services" for Apple that can be payed by Paypal in iOS app?

Tags: ios, paypal, app-store, payment, appstore-approval

According to Apple rules, it's allowed to use external payment methods like Paypal for goods and services "used outside of the application" or for "real-world services".

[App Store Review Guidelines:](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

> **11.2** Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
> rejected
>
> **11.3** Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

We have an Internet service with paid options, like Dropbox or Skype. The service can be used "outside the application" - in the literal sense of these words: it can be used with the iOS application or without it, inside or outside it.

The quesion is: are Internet services like Dropbox or Skype "real-world", so they can use Paypal as a payment method, or are they "unreal world", and **should** use In App Purchases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  If your service is delivered digitally it does not qualify--you will not be allowed to use your own payment system in your app, nor will you be allowed to even link outside your app to a payment system.  In my experience even putting the name of your website in the app is considered by Apple to be circumventing their in-app purchase rules.

If your service is a physical good (like a gym membership or a dog walking service), then yes.

There are plenty of articles about this on the Internet.  eg: http://www.macrumors.com/2013/04/03/skydrive-3-0-appears-in-app-store-following-apple-microsoft-conflict-over-subscription-options/

Comment: This is sad. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Apple's ecosystem.  ;)

Comment: In your opinion, could a carrier (mobile phone network) sell a subscription using PayPal? Or do they have to use IAP? To make it more complicated: Carriers also often sell smartphones. Would they have to use IAP for the service and non-IAP for the devices?